# Homebrew errors - I can't find the resolution

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to upgrade to ruby 2.0.0 from ruby 1.9.3. I can't do that because I get an error saying in need lib tool. The advice on getting libtool leads me to Homebrew. I had it previously but removed it because it wouldn't let me install anything. I kept getting a long list of errors but no advice on how to address them. My current brew doctor error list is:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile

Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.
```

I tried running the echo export PATH as suggested but this error keeps being raised. As for each of the others, I don't know how to resolve them. This is driving me crazy! Thanks in advance for any help that you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a file in Your system /etc/paths, in my system it looks like this:

```
edgarss-mac-pro:~ ejekabsons$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

As You can see I have put /usr/local/bin higher so that executables in that folder would be of higher priority than /usr/bin.

Comment: Thanks. Where are you finding the file you're referring to? Thanks - I'll take a look.